# Angular material - mat-table dynamic footer/header rowDef

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'm trying to conditionally display the `footer-row` of my mat-table.

Based on [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13030), I know that somehow, I have to use `removeFooterRowDef` to remove it and I guess `addFooterRowDef` or `setFooterRowDef` to bring another.

But I can't find a proper explanation on how to use one of these.

Note that I have tryed to wrap the footer-row in an ng-container.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hasFooter">
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="footerRowDef"></tr>
<ng-container>
```

but even if `hasFooter` is false, the row is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100204/angular-material-mat-table-define-reusable-column-in-component), I found out that it is used in combination with `viewChild` like in the template, there is

```
<ng-container>
    <tr *matFooterRowDef="columns" mat-footer-row></tr>
</ng-container>
```

and in the component class

```
@ViewChild(MatFooterRowDef, {static: true}) footerDef: MatFooterRowDef;
@ViewChild(MatTable, {static: true}) table: MatTable;

removeFooter() {
    this.table.removeFooterRowDef(this.footerDef);
}

addFooter() {
    this.table.setFooterRowDef(this.footerDef);
}
```

To add a new footer, we would call `addFooterRowDef` but I call `setFooterRowDef` to override any existing footer.

All other methods for `rowDef` and `headerRowDef` work the same way. And `columnDef` also, I guess.

I leave it here if ever anyone needs it.